# TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter

Aprendiendo POO, herencia. En el ejemplo siguiente, la clase "IndicadoresTendencia()" necesita heredar la variable "df" de la clase "Importa_XLSX()". Para ello intento.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import yfinance

class Importa_XLSX():
    """Importa cotizaciones descargadas de Yahoo Finanzas"""
    def __init__(self, name): 
        self.name = name
        self.df = pd.DataFrame({})
      
    # Seleccionar fechas y cotizaciones.
    def importar_cotizaciones(self):
        ticker = yfinance.Ticker(self.name)
        self.df = ticker.history(interval="1d",start="2000-01-4",end="2021-04-10")
        print (self.df [:3])
        #return self.df
    
class IndicadoresTendencia(Importa_XLSX):
    def __init__(self, name, df):
        super().__init__( name, df)
        self.cotiz_media = 0
        self.cotiz_max = 0
        self.cotiz_min = 0
    
    def calc_cotiz_MediaMaxMin(self, df):
        # Cotización media, máxima y mínima  en el período
                        
        self.cotiz_media = self.self.df()        
        self.cotiz_max = self.df.max()
        self.cotiz_min = self.df.min()
        print (f"\nmedia {self.media}, máxima {self.max}, mínima {self.minima}")
        #return self.cotiz_media, self.cotiz_max, self.cotiz_min   
    
name = 'AAPL' 

cotizaciones_apple = Importa_XLSX(name)
df_apple = cotizaciones_apple.importar_cotizaciones()
indicadores_apple = IndicadoresTendencia(name, df)
indicadores_apple.calc_cotiz_MediaMaxMin()
```

Me devuelve

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-52dd4f29f945> in <module>
     36 cotizaciones_apple = Importa_XLSX(name)
     37 df_apple = cotizaciones_apple.importar_cotizaciones()
---> 38 indicadores_apple = IndicadoresTendencia(name, df)
     39 indicadores_apple.calc_cotiz_MediaMaxMin()

<ipython-input-25-52dd4f29f945> in __init__(self, name, df)
     18 class IndicadoresTendencia(Importa_XLSX):
     19     def __init__(self, name, df):
---> 20         super().__init__( name, df)
     21         self.cotiz_media = 0
     22         self.cotiz_max = 0

TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

¿Qué no estoy entendiendo correctamente?.

Comment: El `__init__` de tu clase `Importa_XLSX` solo tiene un parámetro (`name`, dado que el `self` no cuenta como parámetro puesto que lo inyectará python en las instancias) sin embargo en el constructor de `IndicadoresTendencia` le pasas dos: `super().__init__( name, df)`, qué quieres que haga el `df`?? Por eso el error, la clase está definida con dos parámetros (`self, name`), y tú la llamas con tres (`self, name, df`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Además de lo que mencionas, he visto algunos errores más que corrijo en este script

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import yfinance

class Importa_XLSX():
    """Importa cotizaciones descargadas en ficheros Xlsx, alojados en un directorio"""
    def __init__(self, name): 
        self.name = name
        self.df = pd.DataFrame({})
      
    # Seleccionar fechas para el rango de análisis
    def importar_cotizaciones(self):
        ticker = yfinance.Ticker(self.name)
        self.df = ticker.history(interval="1d",start="2000-01-4",end="2021-04-10")
        print (self.df [:3])
        #return self.df
    
class IndicadoresTendencia(Importa_XLSX):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__( name)
        self.cotiz_media = 0
        self.cotiz_max = 0
        self.cotiz_min = 0
    
    def calc_cotiz_MediaMaxMin(self):
        # Cotización media, máxima y mínima  en el período
                        
        self.cotiz_media = self.df.mean()        
        self.cotiz_max = self.df.max()
        self.cotiz_min = self.df.min()
        print (f"\nmedia {self.cotiz_media}, máxima {self.cotiz_max}, mínima {self.cotiz_min}")
        #return self.cotiz_media, self.cotiz_max, self.cotiz_min   
    
name = 'AAPL' 

indicadores_apple = IndicadoresTendencia(name)

indicadores_apple.importar_cotizaciones()

indicadores_apple.calc_cotiz_MediaMaxMin()
```

El error más importante, era conceptual. Había creado dos objetos, uno para cada una de las clases, sin relación alguna.

Estas dos sentencias no son necesarias

```
cotizaciones_apple = Importa_XLSX(name)
df_apple = cotizaciones_apple.importar_cotizaciones()
```

dado que es importante entender que, la clase hijo tiene acceso directo a los métodos de la calse padre. Una vez entendido esto,creamos el objeto **indicadores_apple**. Este objeto hereda de la clase padre **Importa_XLSX**, por lo que tiene acceso directo a sus métodos y a sus variables.

Comment: debes de aceptar tu respuesta, así comunidad no "revive" tu pregunta